# Configure uWSGI to use virtualenv

Tags: nginx, flask, virtualenv, uwsgi

I've installed uWSGI and nginx through `apt-get` and placed my uwsgi-conf.ini in /etc/uwsgi/apps-available and symlinked it to apps-enabled, and followed the same procedure for the nginx configuration.

(Config files listed below)

The problem is that I can't get uWSGI to start the virtualenv in located in  /usr/share/nginx/www/helloflask/venv

If I add the line `virtualenv = /usr/share/nginx/www/helloflask/venv` and access the server I get a `502 Bad Gateway` error?

and without the `virtualenv` line in the `.ini` file I get this message:

```
uWSGI Error

Python application not found
```

And here's a couple of lines from the logfile:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/nginx/www/helloflask/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from application import app
  File "/usr/share/nginx/www/helloflask/application.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
ImportError: No module named flask
 - unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='xx.xx.xxx.xx|') (callable not found or import error)
xx.xx.xxx.xx {address space usage: 134094848 bytes/127MB} {rss usage: 12623872 bytes/12MB} [pid: 29848|app: -1|req: -1/6] 95.166.70.107 () {44 vars in 721 bytes} [Thu May  9 08:40:29 2013] GET /favicon.ico => generated 48 bytes in 5 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 63 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
```

`/etc/uwsgi/apps-available/uwsgi-conf.ini`

```
[uwsgi]
plugins = python
gid = nginx
uid = nginx
vhost = true
logdate
socket = 127.0.0.1:3031
master = true
processes = 1
harakiri = 20
limit-as = 128
memory-report
no-orphans = true
```

`/etc/nginx/sites-available/helloflask`

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name xx.xx.xxx.xxx;
  location / {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_param UWSGI_CHDIR /usr/share/nginx/www/helloflask/;
    uwsgi_param UWSGI_PYHOME /user/share/nginx/www/helloflask/;
    uwsgi_param UWSGI_SCRIPT test;
    uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:3031;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite clear that you're missing required modules in your virtualenv, by the following output:

```
ImportError: No module named flask
```

Try to install the flask module into your virtualenv, and if needed, install any other modules needed too.

```
source /usr/share/nginx/www/helloflask/venv/bin/activate
pip install flask
```